# "Failed to resolve 'top' key column" Error in Application Insights Analytics Custom Dimensions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have some data in Application Insights, and I am using the Analytics view to write queries against it.

I can see that I have a trace, the CustomDimensions of which contain a property called ActivityID, which is a guid:

[image]

What I want to do is now run another query to return all traces that contain that ActivityId.

Using [this](https://4pp1n51ght5.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/cool-app-analytics-query-using-custom-dimensions-and-measurements) as guide, I currently have the following:

```
union (traces
| extend ActivityId = tostring(customDimensions.ActivityId)
| project ActivityId
| where ActivityId  == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
| top 101 by timestamp desc
```

However, this is returning the following syntax error message:

```
Failed to resolve 'top' key column
```

What am I doing wrong? I would also appreciate and an explanation of the error message if possible.

Comment: The accepted answer actually works but misleading. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a `top` on projection unless you actually include the timestamp column in the projection.

I did :

```
union (traces)
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project session_Id
```

so this should work

```
union (traces
| extend ActivityId = tostring(customDimensions.ActivityId)
| where ActivityId  == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project ActivityId
```

and then it works. What is your complete query (I guess there is more since you are using `union`?)

Comment: That fixed the error, thanks. The reason I used union originally was I had just modified the query that auto-populated after I opened the analytics view, which used a union. One other question, the error has gone but now I'm getting "no results found". Do I need to cast toguid rather than tostring?

Comment: Hmm I always have used `tostring` myself, even for values that could be parsed as a guid. Do mind it is case sensitive! Even stranger, only `==` is. Change it into `contains` than it will compare case insensitive.

Comment: @PeterBons "It seems you cannot do a top on projection" is incorrect. you can do a top on project, but you'll need to project it first :)

Comment: @yonisha Well then, my answer does work, but thank you for the correction and for the opportunity to update my answer. Not sure if it warrants a downvote though. Especially since I did not state it as a fact, I stated that it seemed (to me that) way.

Answer (score 0):

You must project the 'timestamp' column if you want to use it inside the top.

```
traces
| extend ActivityId = tostring(customDimensions.ActivityId)
| project ActivityId, timestamp
| where ActivityId  == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
| top 101 by timestamp desc
```

*Note that you also do not need to use **union**